# Create multiple path style from parent to children in a TikZtree

Tags: tikz-trees

I now how to create a diagram like this:

[image]

After that, I succeed in creating the path from the root to its children so it looks like this:

[image]

Now, I'm trying to make it look like this:

[image]

I created this code:

```
\documentclass[utf8]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,positioning,shadows,trees}

\tikzset{
    basic/.style  = {draw, text width=15em, drop shadow, rectangle},
    root/.style   = {basic, rounded corners=2pt, thin, align=center,
        fill=green!30},
    level 2/.style = {basic, rounded corners=6pt, thin,align=center, fill=green!60,
        text width=8em},
    level 3/.style = {basic, thin, align=left, fill=pink!60, text width=6.5em}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    every node/.style={anchor=center, align=center},
    level 1/.style={sibling distance=12em},
    edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south) |- (0em,2em) -| (\tikzchildnode.north)},
    edge from parent/.style={->,draw},
    >=latex]

    % root of the the initial tree, level 1
    \node[root] {Drawing diagrams}
    % The first level, as children of the initial tree
    child {node[level 2] (c1) {Defining node and arrow styles}}
    child {node[level 2] (c2) {Positioning the nodes}}
    child {node[level 2] (c3) {Drawing arrows between nodes}};

    % The second level, relatively positioned nodes
    \begin{scope}[every node/.style={level 3}]
    \node [below of = c1, xshift=15pt] (c11) {Setting shape};
    \node [below of = c11] (c12) {Choosing color};
    \node [below of = c12] (c13) {Adding shading};

    \node [below of = c2, xshift=15pt] (c21) {Using a Matrix};
    \node [below of = c21] (c22) {Relatively};
    \node [below of = c22] (c23) {Absolutely};
    \node [below of = c23] (c24) {Using overlays};

    \node [below of = c3, xshift=15pt] (c31) {Default arrows};
    \node [below of = c31] (c32) {Arrow library};
    \node [below of = c32] (c33) {Resizing tips};
    \node [below of = c33] (c34) {Shortening};
    \node [below of = c34] (c35) {Bending};
    \end{scope}

    % lines from each level 1 node to every one of its "children"
    \foreach \value in {1,2,3}
        \draw[->] (c1.west) -| (-1em,0em) |- (c1\value.west);

    \foreach \value in {1,...,4}
        \draw[->] (c2.west) -| (-1em,0em) |- (c2\value.west);

    \foreach \value in {1,...,5}
        \draw[->] (c3.west) -| (-1em,0em) |- (c3\value.west);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But it just create this mess:

[image]

Where did it went wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there: just add 3 times `++` in the last three `\draw` commands.

```
\documentclass[utf8]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,positioning,shadows,trees}

\tikzset{
    basic/.style  = {draw, text width=15em, drop shadow, rectangle},
    root/.style   = {basic, rounded corners=2pt, thin, align=center,
        fill=green!30},
    level 2/.style = {basic, rounded corners=6pt, thin,align=center, fill=green!60,
        text width=8em},
    level 3/.style = {basic, thin, align=left, fill=pink!60, text width=6.5em}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    every node/.style={anchor=center, align=center},
    level 1/.style={sibling distance=12em},
    edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south) |- (0em,2em) -| (\tikzchildnode.north)},
    edge from parent/.style={->,draw},
    >=latex]

    % root of the the initial tree, level 1
    \node[root] {Drawing diagrams}
    % The first level, as children of the initial tree
    child {node[level 2] (c1) {Defining node and arrow styles}}
    child {node[level 2] (c2) {Positioning the nodes}}
    child {node[level 2] (c3) {Drawing arrows between nodes}};

    % The second level, relatively positioned nodes
    \begin{scope}[every node/.style={level 3}]
    \node [below of = c1, xshift=15pt] (c11) {Setting shape};
    \node [below of = c11] (c12) {Choosing color};
    \node [below of = c12] (c13) {Adding shading};

    \node [below of = c2, xshift=15pt] (c21) {Using a Matrix};
    \node [below of = c21] (c22) {Relatively};
    \node [below of = c22] (c23) {Absolutely};
    \node [below of = c23] (c24) {Using overlays};

    \node [below of = c3, xshift=15pt] (c31) {Default arrows};
    \node [below of = c31] (c32) {Arrow library};
    \node [below of = c32] (c33) {Resizing tips};
    \node [below of = c33] (c34) {Shortening};
    \node [below of = c34] (c35) {Bending};
    \end{scope}

    % lines from each level 1 node to every one of its "children"
    \foreach \value in {1,2,3}
        \draw[->] (c1.west) -| ++(-1em,0em) |- (c1\value.west);

    \foreach \value in {1,...,4}
        \draw[->] (c2.west) -| ++(-1em,0em) |- (c2\value.west);

    \foreach \value in {1,...,5}
        \draw[->] (c3.west) -| ++(-1em,0em) |- (c3\value.west);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works! Thank you very much. I'll mark your answer when I'll be able to in 10 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```
\documentclass[utf8]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,positioning,shadows,trees}

\tikzset{
    basic/.style  = {draw, text width=15em, drop shadow, rectangle},
    root/.style   = {basic, rounded corners=2pt, thin, align=center,
        fill=green!30},
    level 2/.style = {basic, rounded corners=6pt, thin,align=center, fill=green!60,
        text width=8em},
    level 3/.style = {basic, thin, align=left, fill=pink!60, text width=6.5em}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    every node/.style={anchor=center, align=center},
    level 1/.style={sibling distance=12em},
    edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south) |- (0em,2em) -| (\tikzchildnode.north)},
    edge from parent/.style={->,draw},
    >=latex]

    % root of the the initial tree, level 1
    \node[root] {Drawing diagrams}
    % The first level, as children of the initial tree
    child {node[level 2] (c1) {Defining node and arrow styles}}
    child {node[level 2] (c2) {Positioning the nodes}}
    child {node[level 2] (c3) {Drawing arrows between nodes}};

    % The second level, relatively positioned nodes
    \begin{scope}[every node/.style={level 3}]
    \node [below of = c1, xshift=15pt] (c11) {Setting shape};
    \node [below of = c11] (c12) {Choosing color};
    \node [below of = c12] (c13) {Adding shading};

    \node [below of = c2, xshift=15pt] (c21) {Using a Matrix};
    \node [below of = c21] (c22) {Relatively};
    \node [below of = c22] (c23) {Absolutely};
    \node [below of = c23] (c24) {Using overlays};

    \node [below of = c3, xshift=15pt] (c31) {Default arrows};
    \node [below of = c31] (c32) {Arrow library};
    \node [below of = c32] (c33) {Resizing tips};
    \node [below of = c33] (c34) {Shortening};
    \node [below of = c34] (c35) {Bending};
    \end{scope}

    % lines from each level 1 node to every one of its "children"
    \foreach \value in {1,2,3}
        \draw[->] (c1.west)--([xshift=-5mm]c1.west) |-  (c1\value.west);

    \foreach \value in {1,...,4}
        \draw[->] (c2.west)--([xshift=-5mm]c2.west) |- (c2\value.west);

    \foreach \value in {1,...,5}
        \draw[->] (c3.west)--([xshift=-5mm]c3.west) |- (c3\value.west);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]